# Allot Different Random Name to Turtles in Netlogo

Tags: random, netlogo

I have created 10 turtles in netlogo using

```
 create-ordered-turtles 10  
    [ 
      let b median (list -17 (random-normal 0 5) 16)
      setxy b -12 
      set size 3  ; 
      set color black
    ]
```

Now I want to assign each turtle a random and **different** name using a random function like this

```
one-of [ "Name1" "Name2" "Name3" "Name4" "Name5" "Name6" "Name7" "Name8" "Name9" "Name10"]
```

Which means that all 10 turtles will have names from **Name1** to **Name10**. But no two turtles will have same name.

Also I want to assign each turtle a different integer amount.

Can anyone please guide me how can I do it. I will be really thankful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we stick to your problem description, the simplest answer is the following

```
turtles-own [name]
to setup
  ca
  let names  [ "Name1" "Name2" "Name3" "Name4" "Name5" 
               "Name6" "Name7" "Name8" "Name9" "Name10"]
  create-ordered-turtles 10  
    [ 
      let b median (list -17 (random-normal 0 5) 16)
      setxy b -12 
      set size 3  ; 
      set color black
      set name item who names
    ]
end
```

You can assign the "integer amount" in the same way.  If you want an approach that is not so specialized to your problem description, you could create a `name-random-turtles` procedure and call it with the list of names at the end our your `setup`.  For example,

```
to name-random-turtles [#names]
  let _n length #names
  let _turtles [self] of (n-of _n turtles)  ;list of turtles, in random order
  foreach n-values _n [?] [
    let _turtle item ? _turtles
    let _name item ? #names
    ask _turtle [set name _name]
  ]
end
```